# Вещонка vs. весчонка

Tags: орфография

Как правильно у.-л. от слова *вещь* образовать: *весчонка* или *вещонка*? Думаю, второе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно: ***вещонка***.

В толковом словаре Кузнецова этого слова нет, но оно образовано корректно, суффикс субъективной оценки ***ОНК*** с пренебрежительным оттенком.

Неправильное написание возможно по образцу слова ***песчаный***. В этом случае при встрече зубного ***С*** и шипящего ***Ч***  произносится удлиненный звук ***Щ***.

Фонетические изменения звуков на письме **не отражаются** согласно фонематическому принципу русской орфографии.

**[Суффиксы субъективной оценки](https://studopedia.net/8_15771_IV-suffiksi-sub-ektivnoy-otsenki.html#:%7E:text=%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D1%83%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0%20-%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BA%20(%D0%B0)%2C,%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%86%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0%2C%20%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0%2C%20%D1%81%D1%80.%20%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B6%D0%B5%3A%20%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0)**

Основное значение суффикса -ёнк (а), -онк (а) **уничижительно-презрительное:** старушонка, бабёнка, душонка, юбчонка, девчонка, клячонка, шубёнка, деньжонки и т. п. Впрочем, иногда это значение поглощается **уменьшительно-ласкательным**: ручонка, рубашонка и др. Безударный суффикс -енк (а), лишенный экспрессивных оттенков, производит имена лиц женского рода: француженка, черкешенка, ср. также: нищенка.

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149090/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon--vs-); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.